# How can we use transaction in mongodb standalone connection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I want to use transaction in mongodb but its told to replicaset can we perform transaction query with standalone mongodb if yes please share how to we can because when I try its give error

`This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string`

how to we perform translation without retryable writes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your standalone deployment to a single node replica set. Follow the tutorial to [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/), but do not add any additional members.

This will allow you to use features which require a replica set deployment (for example, transactions in MongoDB 4.0+ and change streams in MongoDB 3.6+).

The main downsides of a single member deployment are that you don't get any of the usual replica set benefits such as data redundancy and fault tolerance. A replica set member also has some expected write overhead as compared to a standalone server because it has to [maintain a replication oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog).

A production replica set deployment should have a minimum of three members. See [Deploy a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set) in the MongoDB documentation for full details.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible and clearly documented in the manual.

Ref: [Retryable Writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/)

Retryable writes allow MongoDB drivers to automatically retry certain write operations a single time if they encounter network errors, or if they cannot find a healthy primary in the replica sets or sharded cluster.

**Retryable writes have the following requirements:**

**Supported Deployment Topologies**

Retryable writes require a replica set or sharded cluster, and do not support standalone instances.

**Supported Storage Engine**

Retryable writes require a storage engine supporting document-level locking, such as the WiredTiger or in-memory storage engines.

Comment: Thanks for response so I can't use transaction without replica set. can I set replica on cloud server (AWS ec2) with using one IP address?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any experience with AWS.